# Infinite loop when running gulp watch

Tags: gulp, jekyll, gulp-watch, browserstack

I have a Jekyll site which uses Gulp to compile the Jekyll files amongst other tasks such as compiling my sass, js files and running Browsersync. I'm migrating to Gulp 4.0 so have been updating my gulpfile.js to reflect this...however when I run 'gulp' in command line and update a Jekyll file, the build now loops infinitely. This only happens when I update a Jekyll file or a js file, not when I update a sass file. Here is my code:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    cp = require('child_process'),
    jekyll = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'jekyll.bat' : 'jekyll';



// =======================================================================
// Browser Sync
// =======================================================================

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done)
{
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
             baseDir: "_site"
        },
        port: 3004,
        open: false
    });

    done();
});

gulp.task('browser-sync-reload', function(done)
{
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});



// =======================================================================
// SASS
// =======================================================================

var sassOptions = {
    includePaths: ['scss'],
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    //sourceComments: 'map'
};

//Auto prefixer options
var autoPrefixerOptions = {
    browsers: ['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7']
};

var styleInput = [
    '_sass/**/_*.scss',
    '_sass/site.scss'
];

gulp.task('sass-style', function()
{
    return gulp.src(styleInput)
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(autoPrefixerOptions, { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(rename('styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});



// =======================================================================
// JS
// =======================================================================

var jsInput = [
    'js/libs/**/*.js',
    'js/site.js'
];

//Compile js to older browser compatible output
gulp.task('babel-js-min', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsInput)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('site.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/js/dist'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/dist'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//Compile js to older browser compatible output
gulp.task('babel-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsInput)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('site.js'))
        .pipe(rename('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/js/dist'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/dist'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});



// =======================================================================
// SVGs
// =======================================================================

function onError(error)
{
    console.log(error);
    this.emit('end');
}

var svgInput = [
    '_includes/svgs/src/**/*'
];

gulp.task('svgmin', function()
{
    return gulp.src(svgInput)
        .pipe(svgmin())
        .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_includes/svgs/dist'));
});



// =======================================================================
// Jekyll
// =======================================================================

var jekyllFiles = [
    '_includes/*.html',
    '_layouts/*.html',
    '**/*.md'
];


gulp.task('jekyll-build', function(done)
{
    return cp.spawn("bundle", ["exec", "jekyll", "build"], { stdio: "inherit" }).on('close', done);
});



// =======================================================================
// Watch
// =======================================================================

gulp.task('watch', function()
{
    gulp.watch(styleInput, gulp.series('sass-style'));
    gulp.watch(jsInput, gulp.series('babel-js-min'));
    gulp.watch(jsInput, gulp.series('babel-js'));
    gulp.watch(svgInput, gulp.series('svgmin'));
    gulp.watch(jekyllFiles, gulp.series('jekyll-build', 'browser-sync-reload'));
});



// =======================================================================
// Define the default task and add the watch task to it
// =======================================================================

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'browser-sync'));
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out for anyone that has the same issue...my Jekyll child process was causing the infinite loop (only when editing a Jekyll file). Updating it to the following did the trick:

```
return cp.spawn(jekyll, ['build', '--incremental', '--drafts'], {stdio: "inherit"}).on('close', done);
```